# How to add a picture beside the page number

Tags: graphics, page-numbering, fancyhdr, footer

I was wondering if anyone could help me with this:
I want to add a picture just to the side of the page number. I’ve tried using the fancyhdr usepackage, but as far as i can tell, it will only allow me to place images to the right the centre or the left of the page. what i want to achieve is something similar to how it was done in the harry potter books, as can be seen in the following picture:

[image: HP-sidenumber]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you extend your question to show how you have been using `fancyhdr` please, it helps as it means people who want to answer the question already have the basics like `\documentclass` and `\end{document}` written, you can use `usepackage{lipsum}` for dummy text